# Android ObjectAnimator

Tags: android, анимация

Делаю преобразование
 `ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(myView, "rotationX", 0, -45)`
По умолчанию точка опоры анимации находится в центре элемента, подскажите как переопределить точку опоры, например в левый верхний угол.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужного эффекта добился, когда перед анимацией установил

```
myView.setPivotX(myView.getWidth()/2);
myView.setPivotY(0);
```